# Convert .txt file to .csv with header in bash

Tags: bash, shell, csv

.txt looks like:

```
2013-04-10;248179;5431;5375.30€;1.49
..
..
..
```

I need a .csv file with a Header:

```
Date       Visit   Login  Euro      Rate
2013-04-10 248179  5431   5375.30€  1.49
..         ..      ..     ..        ..
..         ..      ..     ..        ..
```

Is there a way to get this result with BASH?

Comment: what is the separator on the `.csv` file? `tab`?

Comment: CSV is 'comma separated values'...the delimiter for a CSV file should be a comma.  Granted, the layout shown suggests it is a TSV (tab separated values) file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it, **if** your fields don't contain any funny business:

```
(echo "Date;Visit;Login;Euro;Rate" ; cat file.txt) | sed 's/;/<tab>/g' > file.csv
```

You'll just have to type a tab literally in bash (^V TAB). If your version of sed supports it, you can write`\t` instead of a literal tab.

Comment: In `bash` (and other shells that support it), you can use the special quoting `$'s/;/\t/g'` even if your `sed` doesn't support `\t`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk :

```
echo -e "Data\tVisit\tLogin\tEuro\tRate" > newfile; awk -F';' ' {$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" file >> newfile
```

The `{$1=$1}1` is a trick to force the new field separator.

`echo` with the `-e` forces the tab character to be interpreted as a tab.

Edit : changed pipe | to & and then to ;

Comment: The pipe does nothing, as all output from `echo` is directed to the file, and `awk` is given a file to read from and ignores its standard input.

Comment: Yeah you're right, there's nothing to pipe, I meant a "&" of course :p (but it worked anyway)

Comment: You don't even need `&`, since the echo will complete almost immeditely; just use a semicolon.

Comment: You know what, I think I rarely used the ; in my entire life. It never crosses my mind -_-' Maybe it's time to change that ...

Comment: No need to use the semicolon; just put the two commands on two separate lines.  Or use a single redirection with: `{ echo ...; awk ...; } > newfile` where, if you keep it all on one line (as in a comment) you do need _both_ semicolons, but if you spread it out over 4 lines (the braces on a line on their own, with the I/O redirection after the second), then you don't need any semicolons.

Comment: Or just put a `BEGIN` block in the call to `awk` to print the header.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pure bash solution.Store the headers in an array and set `IFS` to `tab` and then `echo` the header. Loop through the file with read, set `IFS` to `;` on the way in, set
    `IFS` to `tab` and run `echo` on the way out.

```
headers=(Date       Visit   Login  Euro      Rate)
((IFS=$'\t'; echo "${headers[*]}"); 
while IFS=';' read -r -a arr; do
(IFS=$'\t'; echo "${arr[*]}";)
done < test.fil) > test.csv
```