# Linux commandline convert pdf to excel

Tags: linux, excel, pdf, command-line

I'm looking for a tool where I can reliable convert a pdf to an excel spreadsheet from the commandline (as I would like to use a script to automate this).

I need something that will properly convert the pdf, as you would using Acrobat Pro or similar programs.

Answer (score 7):

[pdftotext](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext) This command will help you to convert pdf to text.  [Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba) has the capability to import text data. If you prefer to convert text data to csv please refer the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987474/convert-txt-file-to-csv-with-header-in-bash)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need a direct conversion, otherwise I lose the important formatting.